# AMD Legacy driver in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 on my machine which has an AMD4890 video card. As I have come to find out, legacy card drivers no longer work with Xorg in 12.10. I have found many recommendations for this procedure: https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx

However, when I follow this step by step, I still get no unity after the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a 3rd party repository that provides the legacy driver along with downgraded Xorg that is compatible with the driver:
http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/